# OnCreateOptionsMenu doesn't get called on Android 7.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, toolbar, android-7.0-nougat

As in the title mentioned the **OnCreateOptionsMenu** method doesn't get called after I updated my system to Android 7.0.

Before the update I used *Android 6.0* and it worked without any issues.
If I test it on my other phone with 6.0 it is still working (same code).

Is there any problem with this method on Android 7.0 or is something wrong in my code?

The part of my MainActivity.cs where I set the [toolbar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/)

```
[Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar",ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
         base.OnCreate(bundle);
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

         var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
         toolbar.SetTitleTextColor(Color.White);
         SetActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menu_start, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

**Main.axml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D"
        android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**top_menu_start**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
       android:id="@+id/start_listview"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon_posts_list"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="startListview" />
  <item
       android:id="@+id/start_pager"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon_posts_kacheln"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="startPager" />
  <item
       android:id="@+id/doSomething"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="doSomething" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `AppCompatActivity` you should be using `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` instead of `Android.Widget.Toobar` and calling `SetSupportActionBar` instead of `SetActionBar`. Now your `OnCreateOptionsMenu` will be called.

#### OnCreate override:

```
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.SetTitleTextColor(Color.White);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

#### Main.axml update:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D"        android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```